# .NET Core 2 MVC role based login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a .NET Core 2 MVC project and I have a part of the website totally separated from the other one in my project. These both "parts" share the same set of users.
In one of the parts of the project I want users to be able to see the login page, but only users having specific role to be able to actually log in.

Currently I use the `IsInRoleAsync` method of ASP.NET Identity's user manager, but I am wondering if there is any better solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Authorize` attribute :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{   
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
         // shows the login page
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
         // Process login
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I won't be able to log in at all. Because the POST request action that would log me in is restricted by `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`

Comment: Administrator role is an example, you have to replace it by your own role that can login.

Comment: Whatever role you put in there, it would never work. It's like that because the authorization check would be executed prior to the body of the Login method, where the log in logic would actually be.

Comment: Oh I see, I assumed that your user is already logged in from another "part", and a separate login was required for this particular "part".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use your code like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
     // Process login
     // after he loged in
     // Check if he is an admin, if not log out using :
     await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
     // then redirect to login page with a message
}
```

I hope this works for you.